Replacing PDEBuild with Tycho
I have an old eclipse RCP app that is built by Ant and PDE-Build.
Since PDE-Build is deprecated I would like to swap it out for RCP's new build tool Tycho.
My question is: what is essential to getting Tycho working? PDE-Build takes a list of plugins, jars to combine as pluginPath= can we make the same jars available to Tycho?

You normally give tycho a .product file and target platform so much the same as the old build, but this is too broad to cover in details. Study a tutorial such as this one: https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseTycho/article.html

Tycho supports both, products based on plugins and products based on features. It is recommended to use a product based on features since it is easier to maintain and since it provides more possibilities, for instance including an embedded, updateable Java to your RCP application.
